# Verifying if $||\cdot||$ is a norm on $V$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $U$ be the set of al bounded functions $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.

Define $|| \cdot || : U \to \Bbb R$ as $ f \mapsto ||f||:=\sup\{|f(x)| : x \in \Bbb R\}$

$U$ is a vector space with origin $0_U \equiv 0$

How can I check if $||\cdot||$ is a norm on $U$? It's not the same as just checking that

1. $||x|| \geq 0 $
2. $ ||\lambda x||=|\lambda| ||x|| $
3. Triangle inequality

right?

Comment: Why would it not be the same as just checking the axioms?

Comment: @5xum because I got the hint to first prove that up{$ \lambda a| a \in A$}= {$\lambda b| b\in up A$}

Answer (score 2):

It is exactly the same as checking the veracity of the axioms of a norm.

You do have $\vert \vert f\vert\vert \geqslant 0$ because of your definition with the $\sup$ of an absolute value.

It is homogenous with the properties of the supremum, and same goes for the triangle inequality.

Comment: I got the hint to first prove that up{$ \lambda a| a \in A$}= {$\lambda b| b\in up A$}, but you don't need that to show these axioms right?

Comment: @user423841 I think this is just to make you reprove the properties of the supremum.

Answer (score 0):

Since for any $x\in \mathbb R$, we always have $$|f(x)+g(x)| \le |f(x)|+|g(x)|$$

which leads that $$|f(x)+g(x)| \le |f(x)|+|g(x)| \le \sup\{|f(x)| x \in \Bbb R\}+ \sup\{|g(x)| x \in \Bbb R\}=||f||+||g||.$$

Note that the above inequality holds for any $x\in \mathbb R$. Therefore,

$$\sup\{|f(x)+g(x)| x \in \Bbb R\} \le ||f||+||g||,$$

and hence $$||f+g||\le ||f||+||g||$$.